# Reapply JavaScript code on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried looking on stackoverflow about this and found couple suggestions, however I cannot get any of them to work of me. I am trying to ensure the height of divs/javascript updates everytime the browser window is resized.

I managed to get browser to completely refresh the page without any cache by using the below code, but it is not ideal to refresh the page every time.

```js
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
  }, 100);
```

It is difficult to make the height change at all as changing resolution on snippets doesn't really do much, but I hope you do understand my question.

```js
go();
window.addEventListener('resize', go);


function go() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.text').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
  });
  $('.container .box, .text .box').css({
    height: maxHeight + 'px'
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      We are even height after resizing browser
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a maximus nisi. Etiam tempus venenatis ante, quis iaculis magna aliquet ac. Curabitur sit amet ipsum dolor. Maecenas finibus, lectus ut aliquet laoreet, eros libero semper tortor, nec facilisis
      purus nulla sed urna. Fusce laoreet finibus pharetra. Aliquam ut elit ultrices, consequat dui id, malesuada quam. Praesent semper ex sapien, elementum maximus nibh venenatis vitae. Fusce quis nisi imperdiet, rutrum elit et, ullamcorper velit. Curabitur
      vitae purus interdum ligula efficitur porttitor. Curabitur in nibh non nisi porttitor sagittis viverra ut sem
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      There is more text in this box. <br> <br> yet the boxes are same height
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Alternatively, I have also tried the following javascript code. Both of them are something I found online as I can hardly write my own, yet I am not sure if I am applying them correctly, as they do not work properly.

```js
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.values_text').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
});
$('.us_content .values_text, .values_li .values_text').css({height:maxHeight + 'px'});



window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
});
```

Any help and suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What's this about Java? Are you sure you don't mean JavaScript? They are two very different languages...

Comment: yes, I meant Javascript I just wrote it incorrectly and cant edit

Comment: You should be able [edit] your question whenever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so my friend helped a little bit, that's the code I have now and it's working properly.

```js
function go() {
var maxHeights = [];
$('.values_text').each(function() {
  $(this).css("height","");
    maxHeights.push($(this).height());
});
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, maxHeights);
$('.us_content .values_text, .values_li .values_text').css({height:maxHeight + 'px'});

}

$(window).on("resize",function(){

go()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you used jQuery in the code you provided.
jQuery has a built-in function that fires a function every time a resize happens.

```js
function ajdustSizes() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $('.text').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
  });
  $('.container .box, .text .box').css({
    height: maxHeight + 'px'
  });
}
$(window).resize(function() {ajdustSizes();});
ajdustSizes();
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      We are even height after resizing browser
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a maximus nisi. Etiam tempus venenatis ante, quis iaculis magna aliquet ac. Curabitur sit amet ipsum dolor. Maecenas finibus, lectus ut aliquet laoreet, eros libero semper tortor, nec facilisis
      purus nulla sed urna. Fusce laoreet finibus pharetra. Aliquam ut elit ultrices, consequat dui id, malesuada quam. Praesent semper ex sapien, elementum maximus nibh venenatis vitae. Fusce quis nisi imperdiet, rutrum elit et, ullamcorper velit. Curabitur
      vitae purus interdum ligula efficitur porttitor. Curabitur in nibh non nisi porttitor sagittis viverra ut sem
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">
      There is more text in this box. <br> <br> yet the boxes are same height
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

In this snippet you can see the function adjustSizes() being fired with the JS code when the page is loaded, but also every time jQuery has a resize event.

**ALSO**

If you want the containers to be "responsive" in some way, and for this code to actually run, I would suggest you change width with max-width in the .container CSS so that if the page is smaller than that the container will adapt.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks for the attempt to help, but it doesn't look like this actually works when the window is resized. The height remains the same on resize, however it does work if I change .container width in fiddle for example and then run it again, but that's same as actually refreshing window without cache.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering the function in the event AND after it, you can also trigger the event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {ajdustSizes();}).trigger('resize');
// Or, improved:
$(window).resize(ajdustSizes).trigger('resize');
```

The second parameter expects a function. People often do multple things in the function part, and wrap that in a anonymous function because the eventhandler expects 1 function. But you can just insert that function directly, it makes to no sense to input 1 function, which only excecutes a 1 function.